# Split many lists into 2 sections which contain strings and numbers

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a CSV file which looks like the below:

```
        Hussain 1       0       0       3
```

I have managed to make all of them lists which are created in rows: The lists produced are as follows:

```
['Hussain', '1', '0', '0', '3']
```

I want to be able to sort them so that the names are printed alphabetically along with each person's greatest score: Another note is that the 1st number is to be excluded as this is the student's class number out of 1, 2 and 3 and not part of their score. The people in a specific class need to be printed as the user will decide which class they would like to sort:

If the user says class 1 the program should print:

```
Hussain:3
```

I would appreciate any help as I have been struggling on this part of my code though I have been working on it for a very long period of time. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tuples = [['Hussain', '1', '0', '0', '3'], ['Bon', '2', '1', '2', '3'], ['Alice', '1', '5', '2', '3'], ['Josh', '3', '1', '7', '10'], ['Jack', '2', '0', '8', '9'], ['Zyra', '3', '5', '1', '6']]

class_to_sort = 1

# reduce to classes that are requested by user
tuples = filter(lambda tuple: int(tuple[1]) == class_to_sort, tuples)

# sort the tuples
tuples = sorted(tuples, key=lambda tuple: tuple[0])

# throw out second column and converts strings to integers
tuples = [[tuple[0]] + map(int, tuple[2:]) for tuple in tuples]

# throw out all integers that aren't the maximum per tuple
tuples = [[tuple[0]] + [max(tuple[1:])] for tuple in tuples]

print tuples
```

Outputs a list of [name, max score], which you can then use however you want:

```
[['Alice', 5], ['Hussain', 3]]
```

Comment: I came up with an error which happened to be regarding the use of "map". It stated that it can only concatenate lists and not "map" to list. The error was a TypeError

Comment: Try to replace the line with `map` by `tuples = [[tuple[0]] + list(map(int, tuple[2:])) for tuple in tuples]`. The return type of `map` was changed in python 3 and I testet that in 2.7.